# How to run both JUnit5 plus Spock 2.0 tests in Gradle project

Tags: gradle, spock, junit5

I have a simple project and I want to be able to run both JUnit 5 unit tests plus Spock 2 functional tests. If I have the Spock dependencies in the below build.gradle commented out, my JUnit5 tests run and pass. However, if I un-comment the Spock dependencies in preparation for adding a Spock test, the JUnit5 tests start failing.

my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath(
          "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.1.6.RELEASE",
          'net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.8.0'
          )
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'net.researchgate.release'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
    testImplementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:3.0.5'
    testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-spring', version: '2.0-M3-groovy-3.0'
    testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-core', version: '2.0-M3-groovy-3.0'
    //testImplementation group: 'org.spockframework', name: 'spock-junit4', version: '2.0-M3-groovy-3.0'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.1'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.1'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
   enabled = true
}

bootJar {
    archiveFileName = "app.jar"
}
```

The error I am getting if I un-comment the Spock dependencies:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.TestSuiteExecutionException: Could not complete execution for Gradle Test Executor 3.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:63)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.stop(TestWorker.java:132)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:182)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHubBackedObjectConnection$DispatchWrapper.dispatch(MessageHubBackedObjectConnection.java:164)
    at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.hub.MessageHub$Handler.run(MessageHub.java:412)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.junit.platform.engine.TestEngine: org.spockframework.runtime.SpockEngine Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:672)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1232)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1264)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1299)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1384)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:87)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.LauncherFactory.create(LauncherFactory.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/platform/engine/support/discovery/SelectorResolver
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3137)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3342)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2151)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:659)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$1.run(ServiceLoader.java:656)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:667)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.platform.engine.support.discovery.SelectorResolver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: Try JUnit `5.7.0` or later.

Answer (score 1):

I created a base_app here: https://github.com/robevansuk/base_app/blob/master/build.gradle

```java
group 'com.example'
version '1.0'

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

test { useJUnitPlatform() }

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  implementation 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:3.0.6'
  implementation 'org.springframework:spring-context:5.3.1'

  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.0'
  testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
  testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.0-M4-groovy-3.0'
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    groovy {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/groovy']
    }
    resources {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/resources']
    }
  }
}
```

When I just bumped everything to the latest versions I got an error warning me of version incompatibilities. The resulting page visited contained the below tables, but not well formatted. So I've formatted them to be more readable and included them below:

```
| Spock version | Groovy version | JUnit version | Grails version | Spring version |
|:--------------|:---------------|:--------------|:---------------|:---------------|
| 0.5-groovy-1.6 | 1.6.1-1.6.x | 4.7-4.x | 1.2.0-1.2.x | 2.5.0-3.x |
| 0.5-groovy-1.7 | 1.7.0-1.7.x | 4.7-4.x | 1.3.0-1.3.x | 2.5.0-3.x |
| 0.6-groovy-1.7 | 1.7.0-1.7.x | 4.7-4.x | 1.3.0-1.3.x | 2.5.0-3.x |
| 0.6-groovy-1.8 | 1.8.1-1.8.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.0-2.x | 2.5.0-3.x |
| 0.7-groovy-1.8 | 1.8.1-1.8.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.0-2.x | 2.5.0-3.x |
| 0.7-groovy-2.0 | 2.0.0 -2.x.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.2-2.x | 2.5.0-3.x |
| 1.0-groovy-2.0 | 2.0.0 -2.2.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.2-2.x | 2.5.0-4.x |
| 1.0-groovy-2.3 | 2.3.0 -2.3.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.2-2.x | 2.5.0-4.x |
| 1.0-groovy-2.4 | 2.4.0 -2.x.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.2-2.x | 2.5.0-4.x |

| Spock version | Groovy version | JUnit version | Grails version | Spring version |
|:--------------|:---------------|:--------------|:---------------|:---------------|
| 1.1-groovy-2.0-SNAPSHOT | 2.0.0 -2.2.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.2-2.x | 2.5.0-4.x |
| 1.1-groovy-2.3-SNAPSHOT | 2.3.0 -2.3.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.2-2.x | 2.5.0-4.x |
| 1.1-groovy-2.4-SNAPSHOT | 2.4.0 -2.x.x | 4.7-4.x | 2.2-2.x | 2.5.0-4.x |
```

Comment: That uses a rather old version of spock, take a look at https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example/ instead.

Comment: And it’s not using JUnit 5 at all.

Comment: I thought you'd be able to manage the version bumps, however I have updated the answer to include this for you and pushed an update to my repo as well. There are some version dependencies Groovy/Spock/Junit each have with one another so even though I've provided versions that work, they may be incompatible with what you have.

Comment: Do your test actually run? I don't see  `test {  useJUnitPlatform() }` in the example here, which is necessary as of Spock 2.x

Comment: You are indeed correct - I've added this into the script and it now runs tests successfully from gradle

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using both old and new JUnit engines:

```
test.useJUnitPlatform() {
        includeEngines 'junit-vintage'
        includeEngines 'junit-jupiter'
    }
```

, where `vintage` is for Spock, and `jupiter` is for JUnit5.

It may not be the best solution, but it works :)